# basic difference between value types and reference types

Tags: c#, pointers, reference, value-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between value types and reference types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414906/what-are-the-differences-between-value-types-and-reference-types-in-c)

what are the basics differences between values types and rereference types

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272861/reference-and-value-types-scenario , or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658985/what-is-a-value-class-and-what-is-a-reference-class-in-c. So, now you have two Jon Skeet answers - lucky you!

Answer (score 19):

Consider two variables:

```
SomeReferenceType x;
SomeValueType y;
```

The value of `x` is a reference - it will either be null or a reference to an object which is itself an instance of `SomeReferenceType` or a derived class. *The value of `x` is not, in itself, the object.*

The value of `y` is the data itself - if `SomeValueType` has three fields, the value of `y` will directly contain those fields.

That's a very brief summary - see [Eric Lippert's blog post about value types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx) and [my article](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) for more information. (You might also be interested in my article about [parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) which is related, but not quite the same.)

Answer (score 8):

Value types, as name tells, are values stored in memory; referencer types are (a kind of) pointer to an object (a class, an object, etc...)

From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

A data type is a value type if it holds the data within its own memory allocation. A reference type contains a pointer to another memory location that holds the data.

**Value Types**

Value types include the following:

- All numeric data types
- Boolean, Char, and Date
- All structures, even if their members are    reference types
- Enumerations, since their underlying type is always SByte, Short, Integer, Long, Byte, UShort, UInteger, or ULong

**Reference Types**

Reference types include the following:

- String
- All arrays, even if their elements are value types
- Class types, such as Form
- Delegates

Comment: David Chappell's article is mistaken/misleading then... See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx (Only downvoted because of the stack/heap part. Remove that and I'll remove the downvote.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I've just removed that part, sorry for my mistaken link

Comment: Righto. I suggest you remove the "List item" bits as well :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: you're always right... I still feel a little bit confused with this editor... sorry again...

Answer (score 2):

Variables of **reference types**, referred to as objects, store references to the actual data, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) for details.  They include classes, interfaces and delegates.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx):

> Value Types are structs and
>   enumerations.  Variables that are
>   based on value types directly contain
>   values. Assigning one value type
>   variable to another copies the
>   contained value. This differs from the
>   assignment of reference type
>   variables, which copies a reference to
>   the object but not the object itself. 
>   All value types are derived implicitly
>   from the `System.ValueType`.  Unlike
>   with reference types, you cannot
>   derive a new type from a value type.
>   However, like reference types, structs
>   can implement interfaces.  Unlike
>   reference types, a value type cannot
>   contain the null value. However, the
>   nullable types feature does allow for
>   values types to be assigned to null

Read this: http://www.csharptocsharp.com/node/41

Comment: I guess he's complaining about the one-huge-link you had there.

Comment: @MartinhoFernandes - affirmative - though, apologies for overwriting your edit, feel free to rollback.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a variable of a value type, that variable directly holds a value. If you assign it to another variable, the value is copied directly. When the variable is of a reference type, it does not hold the value directly, but rather a reference (a pointer) to the value. When you copy the variable, you don't copy the value that it points to, but the reference (pointer).

You can read more about in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx

Comment: I prefer to talk about assignment working the same for both scenarios - in each case the *value of the variable* is copied, whether that value contains the data directly or whether it's a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: [C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)