# Ref on a list not changing values

Tags: c#, list, object

I'm moving over from Java to C#, and been coding some example programs. Now I have come across a List of different objects (IUnit) and when I make a call to a certain value in the list to change it's value, it changes all the values. I have added a reference to the List - As per other Stack overflow questions.

So I have the following classes

```
interface IUnit
{
    int HealthPoints { set; get; }
    String ArmyType { get; }
}
```

This is the base class I call to create a list of Army Types (Marines/Infantry). The implementation is the same expect a change to the values inside the class.

```
public class Infantry : IUnit
{
    private int health = 100;
    protected String armyType = "Infantry";
    public int HealthPoints
    {
        get
        {
            return health;
        }
        set
        {
            health = value;
        }
    }
    public String ArmyType
    {
        get
        {
            return armyType;
        }
    }
```

I then initialize the List with the following code

```
 List<IUnit> army = new List<IUnit>(); 
 Infantry infantry = new Infantry();
 Marine marine = new Marine(); 
 army.Add(Marine);
```

Then I have a method, which just takes away 25 from the health points.

```
    public void ShotRandomGuy(ref List<IUnit> army)
    {
        army[0].HealthPoints = army[0].HealthPoints - 25;
    }
```

I then call that method as shown below.

```
 battle.ShotRandomGuy(ref army);
```

However it takes the 25 away from all the Objects in that List. How would I stop it doing that? I have added a reference to the List, so I would of thought it would of taken it away from the the original List. Do I need to clone the list? Would that work?

Or is it more of a design issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you add the same `marine` instance multiple times in the list?

Comment: You've misunderstood `ref` to start with. Your `ShotRandomGuy` method doesn't need to use `ref` at all. See http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html You should also learn about automatically implemented properties.

Comment: Read the following, it will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501374/basic-difference-between-value-types-and-reference-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are adding same instance of unit many times to list. Thus all list items point to single object in memory. Modifying any item modifies that object.

```
List<IUnit> army = new List<IUnit>(); 
Infantry infantry = new Infantry();    

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // adds same instance each time        
    army.Add(infantry);
}
```

You should instantiate new unit when adding units to list. E.g.

```
List<IUnit> army = new List<IUnit>(); 

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // create new instance each time
    Infantry infantry = new Infantry();
    army.Add(infantry);
}
```

BTW you don't need `ref` here:

```
public void ShotRandomGuy(List<IUnit> army)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    var unit = army[r.Next(army.Count)];
    unit.HealthPoints -= 25;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes complete sense. So how would I go about creating a  different instance of each unit, and  thus having multiple objects in memory?

Comment: Ahh, Sorry - I do that already. But It's still changing all the objects values. 

I should of given a better example. Sorry.

Comment: @JamesReeves can you show your code where you are adding units to army? I'm completely sure you use approach from first sample

Comment: OMG - Thank you, I can't believe how I've just missed that. It is obvious that I needed to instantiate the objects inside the for loop - Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to pass list as ref, if you not intend to set army to another list
2. Did you forget to add infantry to list?
   List army = new List(); 
   Infantry infantry = new Infantry();
   Marine marine = new Marine(); 
   army.Add(Marine);

Comment: No It was an example. I should of included the army.add(infantry). Sorry

Comment: Can you provide full code of your application then? There is no reason for such behaviour in sample code

Answer (score 0):

You could keep `infantry` and `marine` in lists, and sort through them with `for`.

Something like this would work for instantiating the list.

```
breadCollection = new List<InteractiveObject>();


for(int i = 0; i < totaltObjects; i++)
    breadCollection.ElementAt(i).Add(new InteractiveObject());
```

Whenever you have to access the contents of the `list` to make changes do something like this.

```
int shotUnit?;    

shotUnit = unitNumber
if(shot != null)
{
    breadCollection.ElementAt(i).Remove(alive)
    breadCollection.ElementAt(i).Add(dead)
    shotUnit = null;
}
```

I believe this would work for your issue.  You could also write something for changing numerical values of properties with the