# C# implicitly updates parameter passed to method with no return type and no out or ref usage

Tags: c#

This is so funky to me, obviously the developer should have used the keyword out but I can't believe this is even working:

```
public BusinessResponse<MyResultType> MyMethod(){

    BusinessResponse<MyResultType> res = new BusinessResponse<MyResultType>();
    ProcessResult(res);

    return res; //this has the values set by ProcessResult!!! How?
}

private void ProcessResult(BusinessResponse<MyResultType> result)
{
    result.State = BusinessResponseState.Success;
    //set some other stuff in the result argument
}
```

My coworker said this is called "deep reference", I can't believe this works in C#. I would refactor to use `out` aka `private void ProcessResult(out BusinessResponse<MyResultType> result)` but I would still like to know why this code works.

**UPDATE**

So it looks like I am incorrect and this code is just fine. Seems the sentiment is, that as a C# developer I should immediately know, since the argument passed into processResult is a reference type on the heap being passed in by value that a copy of the reference itself is made and that copied reference still points to the same object.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference.  If this was a value type it would work how you expect it to.

Comment: ahh, of course, thanks TheEvilPenguin ;)

Comment: Sorry I just accidentally rolled back someone's edit, didn't mean to

Comment: Re: Your update. Yes, you just need to (very quickly) get comfortable with the fact that most everything you do with objects in C# is done by reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Certainly in your case `BusinessResponse<T>` is a `class`, also known as a ["reference type"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx).  Reference types (objects) are *always* passed "by reference" in C#, (akin to a pointer in good ol' C)<sup>1</sup>.

This means that no matter how you pass a reference around, it is still referring to the one *instance* in memory. Which means no matter how you *refer* to it, you're always modifying the same copy.

<sup>1 - That's not entirely true.  What actually happens is the *reference* (variable) is passed by value.  When the function receives this reference (again, think of a pointer to some object out on the managed heap), it is refering to the same object. However, the reference itself was copied when it was passed in.</sup>

The other kind of variable we use is a "value type". These are `struct`s, as well as all of the primitives like `char`, `bool`, `int`, etc.  These are unsurprisingly always passed *by value*, meaning a copy is made every time you assign a value type to a new variable (which includes passing it to a function).  For these to be modified via a function call, you have to use the [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) or [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) keywords.

So when would you use `ref` with reference types?

When you want to change *which instance* a variable refers to:

```
public class Foo {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Foo(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Program {

    public static void Example(ref Foo f) {
        // This will print "original"
        Console.WriteLine("Example() was given {0}", f.Name);

        // We assign a new instance to the reference which was
        // passed by reference
        f = new Foo("replacement");
    } 

    public static void Main() {
        Foo f;                       // This variable is a "reference" to a Foo

        f = new Foo("original");     // We assign a new instance to that variable

        Example(ref f);

        // This will print "replacement"
        Console.WriteLine("After calling Example(), f is {0}", f.Name);
    }

}
```

- [**MSDN: Value Types and Reference Types**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Comment: Yup, of course, I think I was just thrown off by the unreliability of that line of code. It is still best to use the keyword out or ref for better readability right?

Comment: @BrianOgden Absolutely not. That means a totally different thing.

Comment: It is wrong to say that reference types are passed by reference.  All method parameters are passed by value unless you declare that parameter 'ref' or 'out'.  What is true is to say that, when you pass a reference type by value, the value you pass is a reference rather than an object.  You can pass a value type by value or by reference and you can pass a reference type by value or by reference.  When you pass by value you create a copy of the original value.  For value types that value is an object and for reference types that value is a reference to an object.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You are absolutely correct, and I understand the distinction. But even for someone who understands, your explanation is confusing. That's why I didn't quite word it like that.

Comment: _"It is still best to use the keyword out or ref for better readability right?"_  Absolutely NOT!  The ONLY time you use 'out' is if you intend to pass a parameter in uninitialised and then assign directly to that parameter inside the method.  You use 'ref' in the same way except that the parameter is initialised before passing in and that initial value used in the method.  The code you have is exactly as it should be.  You are NOT passing out a new object; you are simply modifying the object you pass in.  Because it's a reference type object, it works exactly as you would (should) expect.

Comment: Yes but when you read that line of code processResult(res) and then the next line is return res; I had a brain hiccup. Wouldn't it be better to use ref to explicitly declare that res is being set in processResult and you can faithfully rely that when you use res after calling processResult that res has the values set in processResult?

Comment: @BrianOgden No no no. `res` is not **being set**, it is being *modified*.  It's still the same object instance.

Comment: So when a reference type is passed by value and the reference itself is copied when passed into the function, the copied reference is on the heap and it is a pointer to a pointer, correct?

Comment: @BrianOgden When a reference type (object) is passed (without `ref`/`out`) to a function (on the stack), the reference itself (pointer) is *copied*, just as if you passed a dumb integer. However, that reference still refers (points) to the same object out on the heap.  Thus, when the object to which that reference refers is modified, the calling function sees these modifications of course, because it was to the same object.

Comment: @BrianOgden When a reference type (object) is passed *with* `ref`/`out`, you're passing a reference to that reference, (or a pointer to your local variable). Thus, when that reference is assigned (a new/different object) in the called function, the original reference (local variable) in the calling function is affected.

Comment: @BrianOgden Glad I could help. When starting in managed languages it's sometimes tricky to wrap your head around at first. But once you do, you'll quickly see the elegance, convenience, and efficiency of it.

Comment: Oh ya I love c# and have been using for years, I just always used the ref keyword in the past whenever I was passing an argument in by reference,whether it was a value type or a reference type. I thought if I passed a reference type in by value that it would copy the object the reference pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to require a little digging; You are discovering the differance in value types and reference types. I am not going to give you my two cents when so much is already online. Here are a few articles
[basic difference between value types and reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501374/basic-difference-between-value-types-and-reference-types)
[Reference and Value types scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272861/reference-and-value-types-scenario)
[What is a Value Class and what is a reference Class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658985/what-is-a-value-class-and-what-is-a-reference-class-in-c) 
 and last by not least, the MSDN article 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx